# hide/show element on click and change CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to build a page where I have some links, and when clicking on them it show a text on the same page. I've done that with javascript/jQuery and it works fine.

What I'm trying to make work is to change the layout of the active link. I've looked for a couple of hours at previous questions on that subject but I'm a little lost as I'm new on javascript/jQuery

**Here is a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yJYTT/96/)**. You will see what I've done. I need help on the layout of the active link. For example, **I would like that to get another color for the text of the link, so we will know which link is active**)

Here is my html code :

```
<div id="fond_soins">
    <a class"asoins" href="javascript:showonlyone('onglet1');" >
        <span class="icon">
            <div id="acu1">
                <h3 class="onglet">Titre 1</h3>
            </div>
    </a>
    <a class"asoins" href="javascript:showonlyone('onglet2');" >
        <span class="icon">    
            <div id="acu2">
                <h3 class="onglet">Titre 2</h3>
            </div>
    </a>
    <a class"asoins" href="javascript:showonlyone('onglet3');" >
        <span class="icon">
            <div id="acu3">
                <h3 class="onglet">Titre 3</h3>
            </div>
        </a>
</div>

<div class="clear"></div>

<div id="contenu_soins">
    <div class="newboxes" id="onglet1">
        <div class="rectangle"></div>
            <h2 class="titre_bloc">Titre1</h2>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <div class="contenu-texte">
                <div class="contenu-texte"><p>bloc 1</p></div> </div>
            </div>
            <div class="newboxes" id="onglet2">
                <div class="rectangle"></div>
                    <h2 class="titre_bloc">Titre2</h2>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <div class="contenu-texte"><p>bloc 2</p></div>
                </div>
                <div class="newboxes" id="onglet3">
                    <div class="rectangle"></div>
                        <h2 class="titre_bloc">Titre3</h2>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                        <div class="contenu-texte"><p>bloc 3</p></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Here is the CSS :

```
#fond_soins {
    height:280px;
    background-color:#FFF;
    width:100%;
}
#contenu_soins {
    background-color:#FFF;
    margin-top:30px;
    min-height: 242px;
    padding-top: 11px;    
}
.newboxes {
    padding-left:30px;
    padding-right:30px;
    padding-bottom:30px;
}
a.asoins, a.asoins:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
#acu1 {
    margin-left: 6em;
}

#acu1, #acu2, #acu3 {
    width:15%;
    height:165px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color: #E5EAD9;
    border-width:5px;
    color:#777;
    float:left;
    margin-right:1em;
    margin-top:69px;
}
#acu1:hover,#acu2:hover,#acu3:hover {
    border-color:#333;
    color:#333;
    text-decoration:none;
}

h3.onglet {
    text-align:center;
    padding-top:135px;
}

#onglet1 {
    display:block;
}
#onglet2, #onglet3 {
    display:none;
}

#acu1.active, #acu2.active, #acu3.active {
    border-color:#333;
    color:#333;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

Here is the Javascript

```
function showonlyone(thechosenone) {
    $('.newboxes').each(function(index) {
        if ($(this).attr("id") == thechosenone) {
            $(this).show();    
        }
        else {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Narrow down your question or you are unlikely to get an answer.

Comment: You want active link different width other?

Comment: sorry for my english :-( In fact I would like when clicking on a link that the layout of that link to be the same as the CSS :hover. Or for example that the text of that link be in another color so we know which link is active. Is that better that way ? Thanks

Comment: FYI, having block level elements, such as `div` and `h3` inside inline elements such as `a` is invalid. Also, now that your code is formatted correctly you can see you have several unclosed `span` tags.

Comment: Rory, thats not the case for HTML5.

Comment: @Alex: but he sure got a point ;) you should not depend on a not yet fully stadardised and supported Scripting-Language as HTML5 just because you are too lazy to close tags or wouldn't switch inline and block-level element order ;)

Comment: Fair enough, to be honest wouldnt do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(function(){
    var links = $('.asoins');

    links.click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('activelink', true);
        links.not(this).toggleClass('activelink', false);
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
#acu1:hover,#acu2:hover,#acu3:hover, #fond_soins .activelink div {
    border-color:#333;
    color:#333;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/yJYTT/119/

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone for your help ! It works now and I understood better the code :-)

Comment: @chridam For example: 1) `div` could not be nested with `a`. (I just close `span` tags and add `=` near "asoins" class, in some browsers it will break markup). 2) I add extra event `click` (it's better remove `href` javascript and merge logic if we using jquery). 3) `toggleClass` instead `addClass/removeClass`. And so on...

Answer (score 3):

Create one new css class name "active" as

```
    .active #acu1,.active #acu2,.active #acu3
    {
        text-decoration: underline;
        border-radius: 15px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: Black;
        border-width: 5px;
    }
```

Now, the small correction on your javascript function, add one more arguments by sending `this` operator as 
**for e.g:**  `<a class"asoins" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="javascript:showonlyone('onglet3',this);" ></a>`
and do some changes in the js function as

```
function showonlyone(thechosenone,CurrCtrl) {

     $(".asoins").removeClass("active");
     $(CurrCtrl).addClass("active");

     $('.newboxes').each(function(index) {
          if ($(this).attr("id") == thechosenone) {
               $(this).show();    
          }
          else {
               $(this).hide();
          }

     });

};
```

Answer (score 0):

I like pure-CSS solutions so I made this for you:

http://jsfiddle.net/vucMe/

It uses `#a:checked ~ label[for=a]` to style labels acting as radio buttons

Comment: your solution is also a good approach but its lengthy in case of so many link. Later we need to use javascript/jQuery to handle dynamically